# Finding the pixel displacement in fish eye images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to plot the displacement of a pixel from the original image to the fish eye image based on the radius from the center of the image.

I was successful in producing fish images in MATLAB using `maketform`

```
testImg = imread('ship.jpg');
optTra = maketform('custom',2,2,[],@radial,options);
newX = imtransform(testImg,optTra);
imshow(newX);
```

the `radial` function here helps me to get the fish eye distorted image.

I need to find the displacement of each pixel in the original image to that of the distorted image.

Comment: Apply the equation. Do you know the equation?

Comment: i know the fisheye transform equation: 

´r_original = p1 + p2*r_final + p3*r_final^2 + p4*r_final^3 +  p5*r_final^4´

Is there an another equation for finding the per Pixel displacement from the image obtained ?

Comment: So, if you apply the equation you can know `r_final` and `r_original`. From that, knowing the displacement is trivial

Comment: oh ok, but how can we get these values via the `maketform` approach ?, 

it always returns a struct with 
`    ndims_in =  2
    ndims_out =  2
    forward_fcn = [](0x0)
    inverse_fcn = @radial
    tdata = []
`

Comment: What forces you to use `maketform`? You know the solution, why would you want to use something that apparently is non-trivial if you know how to solve it? `maketform` is being deprecated by MATLAB so there is even argumetn against using it, more than in favour of using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transformation applied (a.k.a "@radial") was angular, the inverse transformation is given by:

```
u = r cos(phi) + 0.5;
v = r sin(phi) + 0.5;
```

where

```
r = atan2(sqrt(x*x+y*y),p.z)/pi;
phi = atan2(y,x);
```

x,y are assumed to be normalized coordinates (centered and between -1 to 1).